# Testing angular directive using ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to create a test for a directive that is supposed to clear the element it's attached to if the user doesn't have the correct permission to see it. I started by creating a dummy component with the directive attached. The problem is, is I do not know how I am supposed to test the functionality of this when the functions are private and take no parameters. Can I get some help creating the test for this directive?

Here is the directive itself, the `checkRoles` method just loops through the permissions and checks another array to see if the permission exists in that array. If it does then good, if not it hides the element its attached to.

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../services/app-service.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() appHasRole: string[];

  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private appService: AppService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (Array.isArray(this.appHasRole)) {
      this.checkRoles();
    }
  }

  private checkRoles() {
    this.appHasRole.forEach(role => {
      if (!this.appService.hasPermission(role)) {
        this.removeFromView();
      }
    });
  }

  private removeFromView() {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
  }
}
```

and here is the spec file. I started by creating the user permissions and then the one that they need. I honestly do not know where to go from here since the functions on the directive are private.

```
import { HasRoleDirective } from './has-role.directive';
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `<div [appHasRole]="TEST_ROLE">Testing hasRoleDirective</div>`
})
class TestHasRoleDirective {}

describe('HasRoleDirective', () => {
  let component: TestHasRoleDirective;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHasRoleDirective>;
  let element: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHasRoleDirective, HasRoleDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHasRoleDirective);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div'));
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = HasRoleDirective;
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should hide the element if the user does not have the role', () => {
    const userPermissions = ['NOT_TEST_ROLE'];
    const neededPermission = ['TEST_ROLE'];
    component.appHasRole = neededPermission;
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?  Happy to help if not, but I'm a bit late ... ;)

Comment: @dmcgrandle no I still have not been able to fix it :)